# Does XQuery have exit statement for FLWOR expressions

Tags: xml, xquery

I would like to know if xquery FLWOR expression has an exit statement like continue and break?

For example I want to exit the for loop when a particular condition is reach.

Comment: FLWOR expressions aren't really loops -- there's no guarantee that "for" elements will be evaluated in a given order, or even in a single thread; they could all be done in parallel and combined together at once, and as long as the semantics were maintained this would be valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I would like to know if xquery FLWOR
>   expression has an exit statement like
>   continue and break?
>
> For example I want to exit the for
>   loop when a particular condition is
>   reach.

XQuery is a *functional* language, which among many other things means that there is no strict concept of order of execution. Therefore any attempts to do something specific *when* something happens, are not meaningful.

The correct approach is to do something *if* a specific condition is satisfied.

There is no way to exit a FLWOR expression, other than using the **[`error()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-error)** function, but this terminates processing.

One shouldn't worry too much about optimization -- many processors have good optimizers.

Thus many processors will evaluate lazily and will stop the evaluation of the FLOWR expression below, the first time it produces result that satisfies the `specific-condition()`:

```
  (someFlowerExpression )[specific-condition(.)][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

[XQuery Scripting](http://www.28msec.com/documentation/advanced-xqueryscripting) has an exit statement:

```
variable $i := 0;
while(true())
{
  $i := $i + 1;
  if($i = 3) then
      exit returning $i 
  else();
}
```

Or

```
for $i in (1 to 1000)
return
  if($i = 3) then
    exit returning $i;
  else();
```

You can try this example live at http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/demo#JvSLsVh3ZjhvTHecVd9jyE1vEBc=

Comment: There is no exit or returning keywords in XQuery.

Comment: `for $i in (1 to 1000)
  where $i lt 4
    return
      $i
`

Comment: Both links are dead :(

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is quite old, I am answering it as some new people might face such situation and would get a better solution.

This solution would run easily on BaseX 7.6

```
for $i in (1 to 10)
return
   if ($i = 3) then
       $i
   else 
       exit
```

Output will be - 3

OR this will generate the output - 3,

```
for $i in (1 to 10)
return
   if ($i = 3) then
       $i
   else 
       ()
```

Comment: I didn't have time to try this in BaseX, but theoretically this would output nothing, since first time through the loop, because of `$i = 1` it would already exit.

Comment: @Vincent - I have updated the answer. The second one does work with BaseX, I have tested. And aslo, the output will be ONLY 3.

Comment: No, but when I tested this, output is 3 but even after 3, it keeps looping. What the question seeks is something like once i reaches 3, exit on 4